# Show that the sequence $\{a_{n+1}\}$ converges to $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

> Define $a_1=1$. If $n$ is an index such that $a_n$ has been defined, then define
>   $$a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}a_n+1/n, & \text{if $a^2_n\leq 2$}\\a_n-1/n,&\text{if $a^2_n>2$} \end{cases}$$ Show that the sequece converges to $\sqrt{2}$.

---

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$. By the Archinmedean Property there exists an index $N$ such that $1/N<\epsilon$. For all $n\geq N$, we can get $1/n\leq1/N$. If $a_n^2\leq 2$, we have $$\left\vert a_n+1/n-\sqrt{2}\right\vert<2/n<2/N<\epsilon\tag1$$
If $a_n^2>2$, we have $$\left\vert a_n-1/n-\sqrt{2}\right\vert<2/n<2/N<\epsilon\tag2$$$

Add $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get $$\left\vert 2a_n-2\sqrt{2}\right\vert<4/n<4/N<2\epsilon\Longrightarrow\left\vert a_n-\sqrt{2}\right\vert<2/n<2/N<\epsilon$$

Thus the sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$

---

In $(1)$ and $(2)$, I didn't say anything about why I need minus $\sqrt{2}$, cause I didn't find out any good reason. Without assuming $(1)$ and $(2)$ are incorrect, I don't the proof I have right or not. Can anyone give me a hit or suggestion to write a better proof? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.  I did make a fundamental error

==============

Where you say "If $a_n^2\leq 2$, we have"

I'd add "$a_{n}^2 \leq \sqrt 2$ so

$a_{n+1} - \sqrt 2 = a_{n} + 1/n -\sqrt 2\leq \sqrt 2+ 1/n - \sqrt 2 \leq 1/n$ and

===== error =======

its possible that $a_{n+1} - \sqrt 2$ < - 1/n.  Thus $|a_{n+1} - \sqrt 2| > 1/n$

==================

$ \sqrt 2- a_{n+1} = \sqrt 2 - a_{n} - 1/n  \geq \sqrt 2 - \sqrt 2- 1/n   \geq -1/n$ so

======= ditto =========

$ \sqrt 2- a_{n+1}$ could be > 1/n.

I think it turns that these errors are never the case, but we have to show that.

=====================

$|a_{n + 1} - \sqrt 2 |  \leq 1/{n} < 1/N < \epsilon$

And then again for $a_{n}^2\geq 2$

... same stuff....

so for all n+1 > N+1 , $|a_{n +1 } - \sqrt 2 |   < \epsilon$, so we are done.

I couldn't quite follow in yours how we were getting $|a_{n } - \sqrt 2 |   < \epsilon$, although you were clearly going in that direction. (But you put in the expression directly, and your indexing was therefore off by $1$)

Comment: why $a_{n+1}^2\leq\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I could have used a_n for the term and then did the equation with the a_{n-1} term.  It was easier to cut and paste this way.  Actually a_n term would be clearer.  Let me edit it.

Comment: No, I won't edit it.  Then I'd have to have 1/(n-1) terms and that'd just be messy.

Comment: No, I will edit.  It'll be clearer.

Comment: This isn't right: if you replace $1/n$ in the definition of the $a_n$ by $1/4^n$, then what we're trying to prove is false. You need something to show that the $a_n$ grow enough to get close to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Why on earth would I replace the 1/n with 1/4^n?  This is a definition.  If you change a definition to something else you'll get different results.

Comment: In order to test a proof, it is a valid procedure to vary the definitions it depends on. Your proof is insensitive to a change that makes the conclusion false. So there is something wrong with your proof.

Comment: We aren't trying to prove $a_n+1 = a_n -/+ b_n$ if $b_n -> 0$ in general.  That, of course, is false.  We are trying to *only* prove that  $a_n+1 = a_n -/+1/n$ goes to $/sqrt(2).  And it does.  We don't care that it won't go to $\sqrt(2) for other sequences.  Why would we?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: your argument must use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

In more detail, the problem is that your inequality (1) need not hold. To see this, define $b_1 = 1$ and then
$$b_{n+1}=\begin{cases}b_n+1/4^n, & \text{if $b^2_n\leq 2$}\\b_n-1/4^n,&\text{if $b^2_n>2$} \end{cases}$$

Now $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/4^n$ converges to $1/3$, consequently as $(4/3)^2 < 2$, we will always add and never subtract and the $b_n$ will tend to $4/3 < \sqrt{2}$.

Returning to your sequence $a_n$, because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n$ diverges, for any $k$, there will be a $K \ge k$ such that $a_{K+1}^2 - 2$ has the opposite sign to $a_k^2 - 2$ (you never get $a_n^2 - 2 = 0$ because the $a_n$ are rational). So given $\epsilon > 0$, pick $k$ such that $1/k < \epsilon$ and then pick the smallest $K \ge k$ such that $a_{K+1}^2 - 2$ has the opposite sign to $a_k^2 - 2$. Then for any $n > K$ we will have $|\sqrt{2} - a_n| < 1/K \le 1/k < \epsilon$.

Comment: The OP doesn't have the option to replace 1/n in the definition.  It's a definition.

Comment: @fleablood: you are missing the point: some argument is required to show that the sequence gets close to $\sqrt{2}$. In assessing a purported proof, I certainly do have the option to vary the definitions to see if the proof is making proper use of them.

Comment: But if you replace 1/n with 1/4^n then you have an entirely different sequence from the second term on????  In any event, a_i as defined then |a_n+1 - sqrt(2)| < 1/n so for an n > 1/e for any e then |a_n+1 - sqrt(2)| < e. so it converges to sqrt(2).  What more needs doing?

Comment: Okay, so $a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}a_n+1/4^2, & \text{if $a^2_n\leq 2$}\\a_n-1/4^n,&\text{if $a^2_n>2$} \end{cases}$ doesn't converge to $\sqrt(2)$.  So what?  We weren't *asked* to show that all such sequences converge to  $\sqrt(2)$.  We were only asked to show $a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}a_n+1/n, & \text{if $a^2_n\leq 2$}\\a_n-1/n,&\text{if $a^2_n>2$} \end{cases}$ converges to   $\sqrt(2)$ which it does.  So what if no other sequence does?

Comment: Yes, but your proof is insensitive to the difference between these two definitions. So your proof is wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying.